# EXTJS / PHP closing window after save

Tags: php, extjs

I have some code that renders a window from another window.

What im trying to do is close both the windows when the save button is clicked.

Here is the function for the creation of the window

```
function createNewWindowHandler(){

var basicFormPanel =  Ext.getCmp('updateDialogForm');
var basicForm = basicFormPanel.getForm();

<?php

$thisJob = ClassRegistry::init('Job');

echo $this->element(
    'open_window',
    array(
        "id" => 'win_showForm',
        "width" => $thisJob->windowWidth,
        "height" => $thisJob->windowHeight,
        "url" => "'/controller/method'",
        "title" => "Create new Window",
        "params" => array(
            'FilterValue' => 'filterValue',
        )
    )
);
?>

this.up('basicFormPanel').close();

}
```

I have tried to close the panel after its rendered at the bottom, but it doesn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `this.up('basicFormPanel').close();` this will close only first window. You can close another window with same code by providing it's selector

Comment: @yogendarji 's approach will do the trick. Alternatively, you can also use Ext.WindowManager to get active the window and close it.